# Variation of polar angle

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am clear with range of azimuthal angle which varies from $0$ to $2\pi$ however I am struggling with case of polar angle in spherical polar co-ordinate system.I understand that to span the area above the plane, overall it ranges from $0$ to $\pi$.Here is my doubt.

Suppose a point A stationed at positive Z axis.$\theta$ would be $0$ here, right? Now I move from this point to positive y axis with fixed radial distance from origin till I reach y axis.As I am on y axis $\theta$ would be $\pi$/2 which is the maximum limit for 1st quadrant(Am I correct?). So essentially θ varies from $0$ to π/2 is the positive quadrant and $0$ to -π/2 in the other and that's how it varies from $0$ to $\pi$ unlike the polar angle in two dimensional system where it varies continuously from $0$ to $\pi$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polar angle $\theta$ is the measure of latitude (it actually equals $\pi/2 - latitude$ and hence it is also known as co-latitude). $\theta$ is the angle that a point A makes with the positive Z-axis and hence it ranges from $0$ (when A sits anywhere on the positive Z-axis) through $\pi/2$ (when A lies on the X-Y plane) all the way to $\pi$ (when A lies on the negative Z-axis).

The azimuthal angle $\phi$ is the measure of longitude. Project the position vector of A on the X-Y plane $\phi$ is the angle that the projected vector makes with the positive X-axis. Equivalently, it is the apparent angle which the position vector makes with the X-axis when you're looking down from the tip of the positive Z-axis. $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ because the projected vector can lie anywhere in the plane (this is just like the polar angle for two dimensions which also has the same range).

Comment: So If I take my observation point A somewhere on positive z axis and move it anticlockwise towards negative y axis, then $\theta$ will have negative value. Isn't it? So if I am on -y axis, $\theta$ is -$\pi$\2. Am I right?

Comment: No, because conventionally we allow $\theta$ to only take the range $0$ to $\pi$. So if you go to -ve Y-axis, $\theta$ is still $\pi/2$ (look at the definition, theta is co-latitude and latitude is the same on the X-Y plane) but $\phi$ is now 270 degrees on -ve Y-axis rather than the 90 degrees on +ve Y-axis.